# How to disable from 26th to 30th of the month and also Sundays of every month using date-picker bootstrap4 plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

So the task is to disable the dates from 26th to 30th and also all Sundays in calendar.
I am using bootstrap4 plugin to achieve this.

Secondly, the option to choose the date will be from today's date past 2 days and till next 10 days. 
(-2 + 10)

For example: Starting date from today 25th May 2020
Now the user can choose from (25 - 2) = 23rd May to (23 + 10) = 10th June 2020 {{Excluding 26,27,28,29,30 and all Sundays}}

I want to alter the above validations and changes to this code:

```
var date = new Date();

$('#divOutPutViewData').find(':text[id="' + data[i].CandidateID + '"]').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy',
    Value: date,
    minDate: date,
    //maxDate: new Date(),
    clearBtn: true });

$('#divOutPutViewData').find(':text[id="' + data[i].CandidateID + '"]')
    .val();
```

I am trying this code:

```
function LoadDatePicker() {
  debugger;

  var d = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date();
  var n = d.getFullYear();
  var lastdate = "31/12/" + ((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1);
  var StartFromJan = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  $('.date').datepicker({

    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    //startDate: firstDay,
    endDate: lastdate,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: StartFromJan
    //startDate: "01-01-" + n,
  });
```

Comment: Could you please post the all the code that you have tried to disable dates in date-picker bootstrap4 plugin. Maybe you were not able to disable all dates based on your requirement but you might have disabled at least few.

Comment: I have tried to use beforeshowday() and all but it doesn't work. Also I am adding some code I have tried in the question again. Please do check.

Answer (score 1):

based on the documentation

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday

to disable all sundays add

```
daysOfWeekDisabled: '0',
```

and to disable all days from 26th to 30th add this hook

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  if ((date.getDate() >= 26) && (date.getDay() <= 30)) {
    return [false]
  } else {
    return [true]
  }
}
```

Comment: From where we are passing the date argument?

Comment: And how are you validating this:Secondly, the option to choose the date will be from today's date past 2 days and till next 10 days. (-2 + 10)